# If we add one to the largest re-presentable integer, is the result negative?

Tags: c, operators, integer-overflow, signed-integer

This program is asking the `C` implementation to answer a simple question:

If we check the largest re-presentable integer **INT_MAX < 0** and print it.

```
printf ("%d\n", (INT_MAX) < 0);
```

So, displayed output `0`. because condition become **false** and relational operator return `0`.

But, If we **add** `1` to the largest re-presentable integer and check condition, See following program.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf ("%d\n", (INT_MAX+1) < 0);
  return 0;
}
```

and displayed **output** `1`.

Why condition not become **false**?

Also, if we add one to the largest re-presentable integer, is the result negative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If we add one to the largest re-presentable integer, is the result negative?

No. Signed integer overflow is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You may observe as if it wraps around in 2's complement representation. But that's just implementation specific behaviour and the C standard makes absolutely no such guarantee anything.

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 5):

`INT_MAX` being a signed value, `INT_MAX + 1` is causing a signed integer overflow, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The output (*if at all*) of a(ny) program containing UB cannot be justified in any way.

Comment: I *think* it's *necessarily* an overflow.

Comment: @Bathsheba ok, is that is confusing, let me keep that part out.

Comment: I've asserted in my answer that it *must* be an overflow. You're welcome to copy - your answers normally emerge as more comprehensive than mine.

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of `INT_MAX + 1` is *undefined* as you will be overflowing a `signed` type.

The program could output anything, or the compiler could eat your cat.

(Out of interest, this is why you'll see `-INT_MAX - 1` as the definition of `INT_MIN` on a 2's complement system.)

Comment: Hmmm 13th answer that includes "eat your cat".  Hope your kitty icon does not get nervous with all this UB.

Comment: @chux Ha. Yes I guess I do say it a lot. A triskaidekaphobic cat ought to be doubly-nervous.

Answer (score -1):

```
INT_MAX = 0x7fffffff
INT_MAX + 1 = 0x80000000 = -2147483648 < 0
```

Comment: And a truck load of UB.